# How to save dataframe to a subfolder as an excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Here is what my current code looks like below,

```
ws = sh.worksheet('DATAFRAME')
df = pd.DataFrame(ws.get_all_records())
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)

from datetime import datetime

now_ = datetime.now().strftime('%b %d %y %H_%M_%S')
df.to_excel(('DATAFRAME' + now_ + '.xlsx'), index=False)
```

As you can see, the dataframe gets saved in a working directory as an excel file but is there a simple way to save the dataframe in a subfolder inside the working folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function checks if there is a subfolder in this case called "DATAFRAMES" if it doesn't exist it creates it and after that the file is saved inside that subfolder, I put the 'sys.path[0]' because of problems with the relative path among other errors

```py
from datetime import datetime
import sys, os
now_ = datetime.now().strftime('%b %d %y %H_%M_%S') 
address_file = sys.path[0] #actual diretory

try:
    address_file = address_file.replace('\\','/') #string maintenance with directory
    os.mkdir(f'{address_file}/DATAFRAMES/') #creating a subfolder

except FileExistsError: #if subfolder already exists
    address_file = f'{address_file}/DATAFRAMES/'

df.to_excel((f'{address_file}DATAFRAME{now_}.xlsx'), index=False) #Saving the file inside the subfolder via the stored path
```

I also recommend using 'fstring', it's more readable and easier to move, Anyway I hope I helped

Comment: Such an awesome job, Rafael. Does the work flawlessly!

Comment: Thank you and welcome to Stack Overflow! @chk9126